# node express.js render before function complete

Tags: node.js, express

I cannot figure out what will happen in asynchronous app if I render the page before all computations are complete? My `console.log`s are not very conclusive...

Something like

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
     res.render('page.html');
     relatedTable.update(function(err) {});
 });
```

From my prints I see that page will be rendered first. But I cannot fully understand what keeps going on the server. Will some error be raise when operation is complete? Or I can use this "trick" to make some kind of background job?

Comment: Think about this :) function(req, res) {  setTimeout(func1, 2000); setTimeout(fun2, 1000); } }

Comment: Right) won't this produce any errors? Like timeout...

Comment: render will call next() on success, next(err) on error.

Answer (score 0):

Render and updating are totally independent, so you can't tell which ends first. This is a totally valid solution to do something in background.